# Rekonq browser problem

Tags: support, mathjax

I am using [rekonq browser](http://rekonq.kde.org/) and there are certain TeX formatting problems which I see daily. I would like someone to help me out so that the TeX errors are rectified. One can see in this Image that \mathbb{Q} gets displayed as Q itself, and there are other problems as well like, summation doesn't get displayed properly.

[image]

Comment: I remember being told once that the SE team was not going to do any bug fixes for bugs that only appear in non-standard browsers. I don't know if that's still true, though.

Answer (score 1):

We only support the following browsers

- Safari 4+
- Opera
- IE 7+
- Firefox 3.5+
- Chrome 6+

Anything else you use at your own risk.

Sounds like this is a WebKit browser; if you don't experience the same problems in Safari and Chrome (both also WebKit based) then it is specific to this browser's implementation of WebKit, then.

Comment: I had posted a recent problem regarding chrome at meta.stackoverflow. Have you seen it.